# Problems using main.xml in Eclipse (Android)

Tags: android, eclipse

Programming for android is new for me. Therefore, eclipse is also new. I've been trying to create small things. But every example i find i need to edit in the main.xml.

My problem is, whenever i use that file, i'm getting an error. I don't know what causes it. I don't know how to get rid of it.

I've tried to follow guids on youtube. Following it to the point. Still, getting errors.

Does anyone have an idea to what causes this problem? and more important: how to solve it?

```
    [2012-03-26 12:12:40 - No XML] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'cyperia.noXML.NoXMLActivity activity launch'!
    [2012-03-26 12:12:52 - No XML] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
    [2012-03-26 12:13:00 - No XML] res\layout\main.xml:0: error: Resource entry main is already defined.
    [2012-03-26 12:13:00 - No XML] res\layout\main.out.xml:0: Originally defined here.
    [2012-03-26 12:13:00 - No XML] C:\Users\Illum\workspace\No XML\res\layout\main.out.xml:1: error: Error parsing XML: no element found
    [2012-03-26 12:13:01 - No XML] 'default' is not a best match for any device/locale combination.
    [2012-03-26 12:13:01 - No XML] Displaying it with 'Locale Language ___Region __, sw320dp, w320dp, h533dp, Normal Screen, Long screen aspect ratio, Portrait Orientation, Normal, Day time, High Density, Finger-based touchscreen, Soft keyboard, No keyboard, Exposed navigation, Trackball navigation, Screen resolution 800x480, API Level 15' which is compatible, but will actually be displayed with another more specific version of the layout.
    [2012-03-26 12:13:02 - No XML] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
```

Answer (score 8):

This is a long standing issue with Android development with Eclipse. You see this message when you run/debug a project with a .xml file opened as "current document". Eclipse tries to build the xml file instead of the project, thus throw the mysterious error.

A quick workaround would be to navigate to a .java file before you run/debug the project.

You can also select the project from workspace to run/debug it, but it'll take more clicks.

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with this issue for weeks on my main machine, and finally got fed up with it. I installed Eclipse/ADT Plugin on another machine and didn't have the same issue. So this made me think of the most simple solution. Remove and reinstall! I ended up downloading Eclipse again on my main machine and reinstalling the ADT Plugin. The problem no longer exists. Note, I did not uninstall the Android SDK. I left that as is and haven't ran into the same issues yet.

**TL;DR** Download Eclipse and the plugin again and it should fix the issue.